# Using ManagementObjectSearcher to get an exact BitLocker WMI value

Tags: c#, wmi, bitlocker

Good Day All,
I am having an issue with ManagementObjectSearcher. I am trying to query the exact value that i want but cannot find any reference to the precise syntax requirements and I continually receive an error when trying to finish out the code to be what I need it to be.

the specific portion of code that is presenting the issue is when I check for the drives Encryption state(I know for a fact that my disk is not encrypted on this machine, which is why that is the only value i have if'd currently). Any assistance in getting this code to pull the correct value would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried both the "=" method and the "LIKE" method with no change in output.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Check for OS Version
        string OSVer = Convert.ToString(Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", "ProductName", null));
        OSDialog.Text = OSVer;

        // Check Architecture
        if (Directory.Exists("C:\\Program Files (x86)"))
        {
            ArchitectureDialog.Text = "64 Bit";
        }
        else
        {
            ArchitectureDialog.Text = "32 Bit";
        }

        // Check Encryption
        ManagementObjectSearcher Collect = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT ProtectionStatus FROM Win32_EncryptableVolume WHERE DriveLetter = 'C:'");

        string Encryption = Collect.ToString();

        if (Encryption == "0")
        {
            EncryptionDialog.Text = "Disk is not Encrypted";
            EncryptionDialog.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }

    private void Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should inspect the value you get from `Collect.ToString();`

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `Get` on the `ManagementObjectSearcher` rather than `ToString()`? _"Get … Invokes the specified WMI query and returns the resulting collection."_

Comment: without using the `Collect.ToString()` the output wont work in the if statement due to it being a "ManagementObject". My thought is by using the SQLesque syntax for dealing with the WMI objects I should be pulling the value that i need directly from the query but it needs converted to work within the if statement. That's just my thought on the matter. and even when adding a couple lines with `Get` before the conversion yields no fruitful results.

Comment: Are you using the debugger to see the results of `Collect.ToString();`?  If so, you would see it returns `System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I figured it out, thank you for all of the assistance provided. Code is below.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher Encryption = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\cimv2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption", "SELECT * FROM Win32_EncryptableVolume");

        foreach (ManagementObject QueryObj in Encryption.Get())
        {
            string EncryptionStatus = QueryObj.GetPropertyValue("ProtectionStatus").ToString();

            if (EncryptionStatus == "0")
            {
                EncryptionDialog.Text = "Unencrypted";
            }
            else if (EncryptionStatus == "1")
            {
                EncryptionDialog.Text = "Encrypted - SysPrep will not complete";
            }
            else if (EncryptionStatus == "2")
            {
                EncryptionDialog.Text = "Cannot Determine Encryption";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting BitLocker information from WMI requires elevated permissions. Your code has to be running as an admin and you have to ask for elevated privileges. So, I don't use ManagementObjectSearcher to obtain BitLocker info. Instead, I do something similar to the following (modified to your scenario - but not tested as shown):

```
ManagementObject GetBitLockerManager( string driveLetter )
{
    var path = new ManagementPath( );
    path.Server = string.Empty;
    path.NamespacePath = @"\ROOT\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption";
    path.ClassName = "Win32_EncryptableVolume";

    var options = new ConnectionOptions( );
    options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
    options.EnablePrivileges = true;
    options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;

    var scope = new ManagementScope( path, options );
    var mgmt = new ManagementClass( scope, path, new ObjectGetOptions( ) );

    mgmt.Get( );
    return mgmt
      .GetInstances( )
      .Cast<ManagementObject>( )
      .FirstOrDefault
      ( vol => 
        string.Compare
        (
          vol[ "DriveLetter" ] as string, 
          driveLetter, 
          true
        ) == 0 
      );
}
```